# MongoDB Atlas with GraphQL

Tags: mongodb, react-native, graphql, mongodb-atlas

Looking to build a react-native app and was going to use MongoDB Atlas for the database, express/apollo/graphql mixed in there for better querying. Has anyone had any experience with these techs together? especialy MongoDB Atlas and express?

I'm not sure how all these techs link together. Any tutorials will be handy as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) provides you the endpoint where you can connect to the replica set and use mongodb.

This takes over many other factors such as installing mongodb, backups and restore. Also, the endpoint(connection string) provided by MongoDB Atlas comes with built-in:

- Authentication enabled
- Authorized users
- Replica set to maintain HA

All of these factors give you advantages of using MongoDB Altas so that you can focus on developing your apps

Using mongodb atlas is likely to give you same things you would expect from your local mongodb and express with additional advantages listed above

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on using MongoDB and GraphQL in a NodeJs service in the interest of getting better querying capabilities, I'd suggest looking at [GraphQL-to-MongoDB, or how I learned to stop worrying and love generated query APIs](https://blog.solutotlv.com/graphql-to-mongodb-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-generated-query-apis/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=48313357).

Disclaimer: I wrote that blog post.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Atlas just announced GraphQL support for Atlas and Stitch. In a nutshell , you can easily generate/ create Schema for a collection in Atlas, Define access rules, relations and generate queries and mutations. GraphiQL is also integrated to run and test your queries. Check this blog post for more details - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-graphql-support-in-mongodb-atlas-with-stitch